# How to select newest records

Tags: mysql

How would I get the most recent records from a MySQL database?

My table looks like this:

```
NAME   AGE  COUNTRY   CREATED 

JEMO  23    UK        2019-04-25 17:41:29
JET   27    USA       2019-05-05 18:21:20
KET   20    CA        2019-05-06 19:16:12
```

MySQL Query:

```
SELECT * FROM USER WHERE TIMESTAMP(CREATED) = NOW()
```

I want to select users who just created an account, like the most recently registered or newest users. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mysql you could select the user with the most recent date CREATED this way

```
 select *
 FROM  USER 
 order by CREATED DESC
 limit 1
```

OR select the matching date for max created

```
select *
FROM  USER 
WHERE CREATED  = (
  select  max(CREATED) FROM USER 
)
```